# Fastest and accurate way to inverse 2 and 3 variate Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have a code which has a large for loop (100,000 iterations) and I need to inverse these matrices in every loop

\begin{bmatrix}
1&x_1&x_1^2&y_1&y_1^2\\
1&x_2&x_2^2&y_2&y_2^2\\
1&x_3&x_3^2&y_3&y_3^2\\
1&x_4&x_4^2&y_4&y_4^2\\
1&x_5&x_5^2&y_5&y_5^2\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
1&x_1&x_1^2&y_1&y_1^2&z_1&z_1^2\\
1&x_2&x_2^2&y_2&y_2^2&z_2&z_2^2\\
1&x_3&x_3^2&y_3&y_3^2&z_3&z_3^2\\
1&x_4&x_4^2&y_4&y_4^2&z_4&z_4^2\\
1&x_5&x_5^2&y_5&y_5^2&z_5&z_5^2\\
1&x_6&x_6^2&y_6&y_6^2&z_6&z_6^2\\
1&x_7&x_7^2&y_7&y_7^2&z_7&z_7^2\\
\end{bmatrix}

Is there another (special case) method other than (or including) standard method factorization or iterative methods that is the fastest and accurate way to invert these specific matrices with numerical values $x_i$,$y_i$, and assuming these matrices are invertible?

I studied briefly and found out that these are similar to Vandermonde matrices with two and three variables.

Here is one of the sources ([http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~olver/n_/mv.pdf](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Eolver/n_/mv.pdf)) where they discussed the LU factorization of block matrices in the form of Vandermonde matrices.

Referring to other relevant textbooks or research papers is also highly appreciated.

Edit:

**After some research, there are some transformation matrix $W$ such that $WX$ is an SDD matrix (but for some $x, y, z$ values it is not SDD) and I used iterative solvers with roughly on an average of $35$ iterations to solve $5\times 5$ matrix. But few times it diverges.**

**That's why I would like to know a robust and fastest way to inverse these matrices in every loop.**

Comment: But these are not necessarily invertible...

Comment: Rather than research papers, you might try an introductory linear algebra textbook, which will explain how to determine if a matrix is invertible and how to find its inverse.

Comment: I am currently reading textbooks such as **Matrix Computations by Gene H. Golub, Charles F. Van**, and **Iterative methods for sparse linear systems by Yousef Saad**. But if anyone of you can suggest materials that are specifically related to these matrices, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you mean with **numerical values** ? Could you say a little more about your motivation for a quicker method than standard methods (triangularisation with pivoting...). One thing is sure : if for example $(x_1,y_1)$ is close to $(x_2,y_2)$, you will have to almost equal lines, therefore, the determinant being close to zero is likely to propagate big errors.

Comment: Assuming it is invertible, maybe the characteristic polynomial could be found with some effort and then apply Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: I am looking whether there exists a special case method for these types of matrices or which standard method is the best fit for these matrices.

Comment: Could you say why you are interested into these specific matrices, it may help us, knowing the context, to propose an adapted solution.

Comment: They begin indeed as Vandermonde matrices, but I personally think it's not worth the value to try a connection with any method specific to Vandermonde matrices.